# why does datepicker fades away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am working on project where I am currently on jumping from one date picker to another when proper date is selected. I have been able to make the jump successful. However, the focus towards the second datepicker fades away in a very short period of time. 
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<input id="datepickerOne" placeholder="date picker one">
 <input id="datepickerTwo" placeholder="date picker one">
</html>
<script>
$('#datepickerTwo').datepicker()
$('#datepickerOne').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
      $("#datepickerTwo").focus()
    }
  })
</script>
```

Can anyone come up with a solution to make `"#datepickerTwo"` appear as long as date is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onSelect` function to this:

```
$('#datepickerOne').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(e){
      $("#datepickerTwo").focus();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: it gave "e.preventDefault is not a function ... " error

Comment: Add e as parameter to your function.

Comment: $('#datepickerOne').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(e){
      $("#datepickerTwo").focus()
      e.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: Your missing a semicolon before e.preventDefault. Have a look at this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/13765/)

Comment: I have added the semicolon and it is still the same

Comment: Please have a look at the js fiddle in comment. What error do u get?

Comment: The error I am getting is still the same : Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: Try this in a different browser and check if the issue persist.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. The error was showing on my development environment only. After I published it and test it, its perfectly working. Thank you so much for your time.